# Can I start thread in Java without calling start() method?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can I start thread in Java without calling start() method or is there any other mechanism to start a thread?

Comment: for what purpose you don't want to use start() ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the good way is using ExecutorService.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: no.

When you check the corresponding [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), you will find that there are many methods to deal with other aspects of threads; but **start()** is the only method to well, *start* execution of code in that different thread.

Of course you can call

```
someThread.run()
```

manually; but that will **not** cause that another OS thread is brought into existence to execute code in parallel.

In case you are asking "more general"; one has to understand that java.lang.Threads are regarded a very "low level" construct nowadays. We now have things like ExecutorService, Atomic variables, concurrent collections. A good starting point to read about those would be [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html). But is important to understand: even when using an ExecutorService; in the end, when things happen in parallel, there will be some Thread object somewhere; and `start()` will be called on that object at some point. No level of enclosing abstractions can make that part obsolete.

And just in case you were really asking that "how to avoid calling start()"; then you probably have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - in that case; please tell us more about the problem you intend to solve by not calling start.

Comment: Well, depending on how you read question, it's not about how to start the execution of a `Thread` object, but simply a more abstract question of starting threads and/or executing code in another thread. There are many ways to start/use threads in Java, e.g. using parallel streams, `Executor`, or even Quartz if using third-party libraries.

Comment: True. I enhanced my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ExecutorService of the Concurrency API :

```
    Runnable yourThread = new YourThreadClass() ;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
            executorService.execute(yourThread);
   execytorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: It will impicitly start.